# Excel file saved without issue, now is empty

Tags: windows-7, windows, microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, file-recovery

Today having problems with an Excel file on a Windows 7 laptop. I worked with this file last night without any problems.
The file was saved on a network drive and during saving have not been received error.

When this morning I needed to open the file I got the message about error.
"Excel cannot open the file because the file format or file extension is not valid". And also the file is showing up as having 0 KB.

I tried an Excel repair on the file and also opening up in another program like .docx or .txt. Is there any way of finding out what happened this file or fixing the issue.

File server is running Windows 2012 R2 Server. Shadow copies are available and I can restore the file to previous version; however, the user did a lot of work after that time.

Comment: Guys, do you have any ideas or instructions? Can I somehow solve this problem?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think your file is corrupted and it may be repaired using an excel repair tool; I personally have not used the Excel version of this maker but I have used the [**Excel Repair Kit**](http://www.excel.repair/) and password tool and they work well:  follow the link if you're interested  how to repair excel spreadsheet

However, if the user was working for a long time Excel may have saved a copy in the users computer C:\Documents And Settings\UserName\Application Data\Microsoft\Excel\filename.xlsx. 
Another thing, I use Undelete Server Edition and it has worked great for the last 5 years; every time a user saves a file it makes a copy and it stores it for the time you specify.